# How to set null for collections within a index document

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to set null for collections within a index document

```
class Foo {
...
    @Singular(ignoreNullCollections = true)
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "bar")
    private List<String> bars;
...
}
```

My setter looks like this

```
    Foo.FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(bars)) {
        builder.bars(bars);
    }
    return builder.build();
```

Even if no bars are present, I see an empty array in the document but **I would prefer to set a null** and even if I set a null on the above else part I see an empty array.

Comment: how does the builder build the entity?

Comment: updated the logic in the description

Comment: An empty array [] is [treated as a missing field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) (i.e. null)

Comment: Is it possible to write in such a way that the field is not even shown as empty in elasticsearch

Comment: I'm curious about the reason you're asking for this? Is it because you think there would be less characters to store in the `_source`?

Comment: Yes or should I leave it as it is for now

Comment: I think the gain would really be marginal, if not anecdotic